# Can I upgrade docker on AWS ECS AMIs?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-for-windows

Im using the latest AWS windows container server ami:
`Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Containers-2018.07.11 (ami-9e0d5ee6)`

And this is the docker version:

```
version:
Client:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Does AWS have their own docker for Windows version?

Is this docker version that the server is running EE (https://docs.docker.com/ee/engine/release-notes/)?

Is it "docker for AWS"? Doesn't look like it because on docker's site the version is different: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/release-notes/

I ask because it looks like this version is old and doesn't support `From repo/container:latest as blahbalh` syntax:

```
Error parsing reference: "openjdk:8-nanoserver as openjdk" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

I'd just like to know if this is standard docker or some AWS/ECS mutation

----------EDIT:

Ok so i just ran `Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Update -Force` and now Im using version `17.06.2-ee-16`

Is this bad? Did I do a bad thing? Will ECS not work on instances I upgrade docker on like this? I can't find info on if the version that shipped with the ECS AMI was specifically modified for ECS support.